# Do ! methods affect the way an object gets passed to a function?

Tags: ruby, scope, pass-by-reference, pass-by-value, in-place

**Background:**

I discovered (albeit accidentally) that using a `!` method (e.g. [#sub!](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/String.html#method-i-sub-21), [#chomp!](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/String.html#method-i-chomp-21), etc.)  within a user-defined function can actually change the way an object gets passed (i.e. by value or by reference) to that function (or at least it appears that way).

I know that `!` methods are used to alter an object in-place, but honestly I've always thought that using them (or not) was just a matter of preference. I, for one, have always preferred to use the `!` methods for the slightly briefer syntax (e.g. `str.chomp!` instead of `str = str.chomp`). However, the difference can actually be detrimental in some cases. Allow me to explain with the following example.

**Example:**

The example below defines two functions, `change1` and `change2`, that alter the value of `str` to say, "CHANGED!" using the [#sub](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/String.html#method-i-sub) and [#sub!](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/String.html#method-i-sub-21) methods, respectively. They seemingly do the same thing, but notice that the value of `orig` gets altered by `change2` but not by `change1`.

I guess I figured that `orig` gets passed by value in both cases, and therefore the two functions act exactly the same way. But I was wrong.

```
# Pass by value
def change1(str)
  str = str.sub(/^.*$/, 'CHANGED!') # Changes 'str' but not 'orig' (as expected)
  return str
end
# Pass by reference...?
def change2(str)
  str.sub!(/^.*$/, 'CHANGED!') # Changes 'str' AND 'orig' (unexpected!)
  return str
end

orig = "original"
p change1(orig)  #=> "CHANGED!"
p orig           #=> "original"
p change2(orig)  #=> "CHANGED!"
p orig           #=> "CHANGED!"
```

**Questions:**

If objects are passed by value in Ruby, how does the use of a `!` method such as `str.sub!(...)` alter an object that's not even in the same scope (seemingly passing it by reference)?

Likewise, why does the use of a non-`!` method such as `str = str.sub(...)` act differently?

Most importantly, how could I have ever known that these two types of methods (seemingly) affect the way an object gets passed to my function? For example, the documentation for [#sub!](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/String.html#method-i-sub-21) only states that it "Performs the same substitution as [#sub](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/String.html#method-i-sub) in-place."